# TensorFlow estimator input_fn with very huge dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, dataset, bigdata

How can I train a TensorFlow Estimator using an [input_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn) such that the actual data (both features and labels) doesn't fit in memory?

Concretely, my training data looks like this:

```
// training.txt
0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004,(...)
1, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008,(...)
(...)
```

The first item in each row is the label (this is for a classification problem), and the rest of the values in the line is a long list of floats. Each line has 16,001 values. The file has tens of millions of lines.

I've thought about splitting the input file into lots of smaller files, so each file would fit in memory, but I don't see a clean way to switch which file to use at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the tensor-flow's dataset API, return the dataset from your `input_fn`.